# Laravel Passport Generate Refresh Token for API

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-passport

I have an **existing** API that uses Laravel Passport to grant access tokens.

How do I use Laravel Passport to retrieve refresh tokens without accessing an http endpoint?

So the access token is accessed like this:

```
$user->createToken('AppName')->accessToken;
```

How do I get the refresh token?

I'm thinking something along these lines:

```
$user->createRefreshToken($accessToken)->refreshToken();
```

Comment: you can use this https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/10.x/src/RefreshTokenRepository.php#L13   `Passport::refreshToken()->create($attributes);`

Comment: How do I do that in Passport 7.3?

Comment: i think you can directly write to db https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/7.0/database/migrations/2016_06_01_000003_create_oauth_refresh_tokens_table.php

Comment: @KamleshPaul what do I put for the ID of the oauth refresh token db?

Comment: Found `getNewRefreshToken()` in `RefreshTokenRepository` but I don't know how to access the code from my Laravel API.

Comment: it is on latest Passport which veriosn your using ?

Comment: laravel passport v7.3

Comment: update that then you will be able to use `RefreshTokenRepository`